# What is the name of the document center standard web apps(web parts)? see picture

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, document, document-center

I created a standard Document center subsite for my site.

When I open the document center I see two web apps. I want to add more off thees web apps, but don't know which apps to add.

What are the web apps name for the web apps marked below?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Open webpart properties drop down, and choose export. You will get the info needed in the file you get (just open it with notepad). If the option is not availabe you might need to set it in the properties (Allow export). If this is not available it is probably a listview webpart

Comment: Hi, I just found it myselves.



You have to add the "content query" web app.

More exactly "content rollup" -> "Content Query"



B